# ¿Por qué sale a la inversa el orden de los botones del String opciones de un JOptionPane.showOptionDialog?

Tags: java, java-swing, joptionpane

Me han pasado el código de una clase en Java llamada Calculadora.

En él hay un `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` donde se muestran tres botones con las opciones del `String` opciones.

No entiendo porque al ejecutar el programa el orden de las opciones en la ventana es: Salir, Multiplicar y sumar, cuando en el `String` el orden es a la inversa. He buscado información pero no encuentro nada que me resuelva esa duda.

Os paso el código de la clase.

```
public class Calculadora {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String opciones[] = {"Sumar", "Multiplicar", "Salir"};
    int eleccion = 0;
    do {
        eleccion = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Selecciona una opción", "Medio Calculadora", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, opciones, 0);

        switch (eleccion) {
            case 0:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Muy buenas vamos a sumar 2 números enteros positivos\n"
                        + "por favor inserta dos números");
                int sum1 = pedirNumero();
                if (sum1 < 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has insertado un número no aceptado por el sistema", "Numero negativo", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                int sum2 = pedirNumero();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El resultado es: " + sumar(sum1, sum2));
                break;
            case 1:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Muy buenas vamos a calcular la de multiplicar de un número entre 1 y 20\n"
                        + "por favor inserta este número");
                int num1 = pedirNumero();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, multiplicar(num1));
                break;
            case 2:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Esperamos tenerte pronto de vuelta");
                break;
        }
    } while (eleccion != 2);
}
```

[image: calculadora_orden_opciones]

Comment: He probado tu programa y a mi me funciona bien: podrias mostrar una imagen de como te sale?

Comment: La acabo de subir al mensaje principal porque no sabía como poner en un comentario una imagen.

Comment: Si hacés un println de `eleccion.getComponentOrientation()`, ¿qué texto se muestra en consola?

Comment: Hola, es un comportamiento "normal", revisa mi respuesta, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es debido a la plataforma, en Windows los botones se muestran de izquierda a derecha, mientras que en MacOS los botones se muestren de derecha a izquierda.

Por ejemplo mira en Windows tendiendo las opciones:

```
String opciones[] = {"Sumar", "Multiplicar", "Salir"};
```

se muestran de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Si deseas que en determinada plataforma se vean en otro orden, necesitarías cambiar el orden en el array de las opciones, pero en otra plataforma se mostrarían en posición diferente.**

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la aclaración. Me estaba volviendo loco buscando un posible fallo ya que tengo que hacer pruebas de caja blanca y caja negra y no sabía porque ocurría eso.